# DevOps in Snowflake(instance on AWS)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We would be doing a POC on having a DevOps with Snowflake. I wanted to know which tools can be used referred to and any doc/implementation references would be helpful.

1. Version controlling should be there.
2. Code rollback scenarios(like all versions of DB object should be tracked)
   To elaborate, if a table is deployed to Snowflake as part of 5 changes
   which is expected to have 5 versions (V1, V2, V3, V4, V5), then in this case if we want
   to see the version V2(code) of the table then we should see that.
3. CI~CD pipeline implementation.

Thanks in advance for all your inputs.

Regards,
Somen Swain

Comment: "having a DevOps" what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean, currently in our area things are happening manually, example: 1. Code promotion from lower to higher environment is manual, 2. No versions are maintained of a code, 3. No CI~CD pipelines are there. We know that GITHUB has solutions for few but specifically I wanted to understand details around how to integrate that with Snowflake.   Example tools like SchemaChange, Flyway. Actual implementation experience & how to even achieve this I wanted some pointers..    I hope I am clear.

Comment: I would recomment to start in the simplest way possible and use what GitHub offers. You can integrate or move to a different platform later. You might need to re-write stuff, but you will have to rewrite continuously anyway as you progress with your learning. DO NOT aim for the perfect one-shot solution at this point as you neither understand the methods nor the tech! Your boss won't believe you, but you will remember my comment in a few months/years and understand why I am right.